# изменение state в одном react-компоненте по кнопке из другого компонента

Tags: reactjs, state

Подскажите пожалуйста пример кода ( или ссылку ) для ситуации , когда по нажатию кнопки в одном react компоненте нужно изменить state в другом

Comment: посмотри в сторону [redux](https://redux.js.org/)

Comment: эммм а просто на реакте ?

Comment: @Мik просто на реакте только если оба компонента будут находиться в третьем компоненте и будут работать по схеме `клик кнопки 1 -> событие -> изменение стейта родителя -> перерисовка компонента 2, используя в props значения из стейта родителя`

Comment: нет примера или ссылки ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так...

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
name: 'Бумеранг вернулся назад'
 }

render() {
  return (
<div>
    <button onClick={() => { this.props.updateData(this.state.name)}}>Запустить бумеранг</button>
</div>
  )
 }
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
 state = {
    name: 'Бумеранг не запущен'
  };

 updateData = (value) => {
 this.setState({ name: value })
 }

   render() {
   return (
  <div>
    <p>State: {this.state.name}</p>
    <ChildComponent updateData={this.updateData} />
  </div>
   )
  }
 }

render(<ParentComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```